# How to check the output of file.txt in Kafka Consumer?

Tags: file-upload, apache-kafka, flume-ng

I am trying to integrate Flume with Kafka and I want to pass a file from my local machine to Flume and then to Kafka. I want to see the contents of my file in Kafka Consumer.

Here is my config file in Flume:

```
# example.conf: A single-node Flume configuration

 # Name the components on this agent
 a1.sources = r1
 a1.sinks = k1
 a1.channels = c1

 # Describe/configure the source
 a1.sources.r1.type = exec
 a1.sources.r1.command = cat /Users/myname/Downloads/file.txt

 # Describe the sink
 #a1.sinks.k1.type = logger
  a1.sinks.k1.type         = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
  a1.sinks.k1.topic = k1
  a1.sinks.k1.brokerList = kafkagames-1:9092,kafkagames-2:9092
  a1.sinks.sink1.batchSize = 20

  # Use a channel which buffers events in memory
  a1.channels.c1.type = memory
  a1.channels.c1.capacity = 10000
  a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 10000

  # Bind the source and sink to the channel
  a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
  a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

I am not sure how to start Kafka from Flume and see the content of file.txt in Kafka Consumer. Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since Kafka is a message broker "service", you have to run it before producing a message with your Flume producer. After the producer produces (puts) a message to a Kafka topic (a kind of a buffer), you can consume (get) the message with a Kafka consumer.

How to start Kafka service:
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart